# base64 encode PHP generated image without writing the image to disk

Tags: php, image, base64, php-gd

I'm generating an image in PHP for use in a users avatar.

I start by hashing the username and then doing a `hexdec()` conversion on various substrings of the hash to build up a set of RGB colours.

```
//create image
$avatarImage = imagecreate(250, 250);

// first call to imagecolorallocate sets the background colour
$background = imagecolorallocate($avatarImage, hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 2)), hexdec(substr($hash, 2, 2)), hexdec(substr($hash, 4, 2)));

//write the image to a file
$imageFile = 'image.png';
imagepng($avatarImage, $imageFile);

//load file contents and base64 encode
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imageFile));

//build $src dataURI.
$src = 'data: ' . mime_content_type($imageFile) . ';base64,' . $imageData;
```

Ideally I'd not use the intermediate step and would skip writing the image out onto disk, although I'm not sure how best to implement this?

I've tried passing `$avatarImage` directly to `base64_encode()` but that expects a string so doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use output buffering to capture the image data and then use it as desired:

```
ob_start ( ); // Start buffering
imagepng($avatarImage); // output image
$imageData = ob_get_contents ( ); // store image data
ob_end_clean ( ); // end and clear buffer
```

For convenience you could create a new function to handle image encoding:

```
function createBase64FromImageResource($imgResource) {
  ob_start ( );
  imagepng($imgResource);
  $imgData = ob_get_contents ( );
  ob_end_clean ( );

  return base64_encode($imgData);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `imagepng` to a variable:

```
//create image
$avatarImage = imagecreate(250, 250);

//whatever image manipulations you do

//write the image to a variable
ob_start();
imagepng($avatarImage);
$imagePng = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//base64 encode
$imageData = base64_encode($imagePng);

//continue
```